# A problem about the code in java especially in skip function

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, skip

```
scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
```

can anyone please explain this code...
i'm still confusing about this code and how this code works while compiling

Comment: Which part don't you understand, the skip or the regular expression? Btw. for both there is good documentation available.

Answer (score 1):

```
  scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
```

You can read all the details of predefined character classes:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Look for horizontal white space and linebreak matcher.

Answer (score 0):

This code tells scanner to [skip unwanted characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip(java.lang.String)) in the input ignoring delimiters.

In this case, a set of characters related to new-line handling are skipped:

- a pair of `\r\n` CRLF as in Windows
- or any of the following single characters:

  - `\r` - CR (carriage-return) MacOS line separator
  - `\n` - LF (line-feed) Unix line separator
  - `\u2028` - [Unicode line separator](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm)
  - `\u2029` - [Unicode paragraph separator](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm)
  - `\u0085` - [Unicode next line](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/index.htm)

Comment: "sets up" scanner might be misunderstood as an ongoing thing. It's not. The code is not "setting up" a condition, it is executing the *skip* right then and there, from the current position of the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for the string:

`\r\n` - a pair of CRLFs like in Windows, or any of the following single characters:

`\r` - CR (carriage return) MacOS line separator,

`\n` - LF (line feed) Unix line separator,

`\u2028` - Unicode line separator,

`\u2029` - Unicode paragraph separator,

`\u0085` - Unicode next line.